# Eclipse Tycho build fails after upgrading from tycho 0.22.0 to 0.23.0. Unsatisfied Dependencies after mirror tool warnings

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, tycho

I am trying to build an Eclipse E4 RCP application using Maven and Tycho targetting multiple platforms.

My build poms work perfectly fine at tycho version 0.22.0 but I would like to upgrade to tycho 0.23.0 since I upgraded to Eclipse Mars recently

After the tycho version upgrade I started getting the following errors and the suggestion on the website is to file a bug report.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Here's an excerpt from the console after the warnings start to appear.

Thanks
Doros

```
[WARNING] Mirror tool: Problems resolving provisioning plan.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from toolinggtk.linux.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.; Unable to satisfy dependency from toolinggtk.linux.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.]
[WARNING] More information on the preceding warning(s) can be found here:
[WARNING] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Mirror_tool
[WARNING] Mirror tool: Problems resolving provisioning plan.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from toolinggtk.linux.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.; Unable to satisfy dependency from toolinggtk.linux.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.]
[WARNING] More information on the preceding warning(s) can be found here:
[WARNING] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Mirror_tool
[WARNING] Mirror tool: Problems resolving provisioning plan.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingwin32.win32.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.; Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingwin32.win32.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.]
[WARNING] More information on the preceding warning(s) can be found here:
[WARNING] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Mirror_tool
[WARNING] Mirror tool: Problems resolving provisioning plan.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.; Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingwin32.win32.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.]
[WARNING] More information on the preceding warning(s) can be found here:
[WARNING] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Mirror_tool
[WARNING] Mirror tool: Problems resolving provisioning plan.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingcocoa.macosx.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.; Unable to satisfy dependency from toolingcocoa.macosx.x86_64org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 to bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455.]
[WARNING] More information on the preceding warning(s) can be found here:
[WARNING] - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho_Messages_Explained#Mirror_tool
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-repository-plugin:0.23.0:archive-repository (default-archive-repository) @ com.mycompany.mysoftware.product ---
[INFO] Building zip: C:\workspaces\mars.e4\com.mycompany.mysoftware.product\target\com.mycompany.mysoftware.product-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.23.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) @ com.mycompany.mysoftware.product ---
[INFO] Installing product mysoftware product for environment linux/gtk/x86 to C:\workspaces\mars.e4\com.mycompany.mysoftware.product\target\products\mysoftware product\linux\gtk\x86
Installing mysoftware product 0.0.1.201509101622.
Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
 Software being installed: mysoftware 0.0.1.201509101622 (mysoftware product 0.0.1.201509101622)
 Missing requirement: toolinggtk.linux.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 0.0.1.201509101622 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 1.1.300.v20150423-1455' but it could not be found
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: mysoftware 0.0.1.201509101622 (mysoftware product 0.0.1.201509101622)
  To: toolingmysoftware product.configuration [0.0.1.201509101622]
 Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: toolingmysoftware product.configuration 0.0.1.201509101622
  To: toolinggtk.linux.x86org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins [0.0.1.201509101622]
Application failed, log file location: C:\workspaces\mars.e4\com.mycompany.mysoftware.aggregator\workspace\.metadata\.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.targetdefinition SUCCESS [  0.320 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.shared.libs ............... SUCCESS [  1.541 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs .................... SUCCESS [  1.428 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib ............ SUCCESS [  1.359 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.model ..................... SUCCESS [  1.172 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware ................ SUCCESS [  2.938 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.model.prod ................ SUCCESS [  0.281 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.model.service ............. SUCCESS [  0.344 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.platspec.win32 . SUCCESS [  0.303 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.platspec.win64 . SUCCESS [  0.342 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.feature ........ SUCCESS [  0.274 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.win32 ...... SUCCESS [  0.312 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.win64 ...... SUCCESS [  0.326 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.feature .... SUCCESS [  0.130 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mylibs.feature ............ SUCCESS [  0.079 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.product ........ FAILURE [  7.461 s]
[INFO] com.mycompany.mysoftware.aggregator ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 39.003 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-10T19:22:46+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 81M/848M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.23.0:materialize-products (materialize-products) on project com.mycompany.mysoftware.product: Installation of product mysoftware product for environment linux/gtk/x86 failed: Call to p2 director application failed with exit code 13. Program arguments were: [-metadataRepository, file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.product/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.product/target/targetPlatformRepository/, -artifactRepository, file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.product/target/,file:/resolution-context-artifacts@C:%5Cworkspaces%5Cmars.e4%5Ccom.mycompany.mysoftware.product,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.product/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.feature/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.feature/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs.feature/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.model/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.shared.libs/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.model.prod/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.model.service/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.platspec.win32/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.win32/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mysoftware.platspec.win64/target/,file:/C:/workspaces/mars.e4/com.mycompany.mylibs.somelib.win64/target/,file:/C:/Users/myname/.m2/repository/, -installIU, mysoftware product, -destination, C:\workspaces\mars.e4\com.mycompany.mysoftware.product\target\products\mysoftware product\linux\gtk\x86, -profile, DefaultProfile, -profileProperties, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true, -roaming, -p2.os, linux, -p2.ws, gtk, -p2.arch, x86]. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :com.mycompany.mysoftware.product
```

Comment: I had the same problem right now. With Tycho 1.0.0 and higher versions I got this error message. When I set the Tycho version to 0.22.0 it worked. And I have no clue what the problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the build to work properly by adding the following feature in my product's dependencies tab.

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature
```

I had also raised a bug report on the eclipse [bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477089)

Answer (score 0):

File a bug here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs and downgrade to 0.22.0

You are not required to go to 0.23.0 because you switched to the Mars release.

Comment: I agree that I don't have to move to 0.23.0 so for now I am on 0.22.0. I would however like to understand what the problem is because soon I would like to build a Mac OS X version with the new .app structure which I am pretty sure requires Eclipse Mars with Tycho 0.23.0